# Is there a less blunt way of bring base class methods into a child class?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider

```
struct Base
{
    int foo(int);
    int foo(int, int);
};

struct Child : Base
{
    using Base::foo;
    int foo(int, int, int);
};
```

Ideally I want to bring the `Base` class `foo` that takes only one `int` as a parameter into the `Child` class, and not the one that takes 2 `int`s. Is there a way I can do that? My writing `using Base::foo;` brings in both `foo` methods of `Base`.

Comment: Quite a weird design: even if you can do it (see answers below) imagine this :`Base* bPtr = someCondition? new Base(): new Child(); bPtr->foo(3);` That perfecly valid, and it's going to call `Child::foo(int)`, which you don't want. The question is: why do you want to use inheritance (is-a relation) and act as if Child is-not-a Base?

Comment: This is a substantially cut down version of the real code.

Comment: I can understand this, but the problem remains: you are using inheritance (and possibly you have some good reasons to use it), but you want your inherited class to be considered "not-a" Base": that's code smell to me. Can you exclude now any code as the one I wrote above? can you exclude it in the future? What will happen if someone call the undesired `Base::foo(int, int)` on a derived instance?

Comment: I think the *real* solution would be to use composition over inheritance.

Comment: @SebastianJohnHoward  What could possibly make that the case? What could you possibly be doing that validates this behavior?  Sounds like you need to make another class with only `foo(int)` and inherit from that.  But as you say this is the 'substantially' cut down version, it appears you are going to run into some major maintainability with this pattern.  With out further context we have no choice but to assume you are doing something wrong to make this necessary, and that you shouldn't be using inheritance for this at all.

Comment: Look up the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), and check if your desired code adheres to it. If not, it's better to rethink your code, to avoid later regret. (Hint: if your subclass doesn't have one of the two functions, can you substitute superclass with subclass? )

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A using declaration will make all overloads available. You can't prevent that from happening. But you can `delete` the overloads you don't want, after the fact:

```
struct Base
{
    int foo(int);
    int foo(int, int);
};

struct Child : Base
{
    using Base::foo;
    int foo(int, int) = delete;
    int foo(int, int, int);
};
```

Now using the two int overloads with a `Child` is ill-formed. However that's not a perfect solution, since a client can still call the Base version:

```
Child c;
c.Base::foo(0, 0);
```

Comment: That's amazing! Thank you.

Comment: @SebastianJohnHoward - Don't be too happy. There's a caveat :)

Comment: note that `=delete` doesn't block overload resolution from finding `foo(int,int)`, it just makes it an error if it is chosen.  This is different than "just using the one argument `foo`".

Comment: @Yakk - True. But I gathered from the OP that the aim is to block its availability, like overloading without a using declaration does. This is a similar effect, I think.

Comment: @StoryTeller It is a similar effect, but not the same.  If you didn't `using` or `delete`, test for `Child c; c.foo(7,7);` would fail at overload resolution time (the overload wouldn't be found) (possibly selecting a different one).  With the `using` and `=delete`, it (the two int overload) can be found and chosen via overload resolution.  Only after it is chosen does an error occur.

Answer (score 10):

It's not possible to bring the specified overloaded function into the derived class. The rule of name lookup deals with names, but the overloaded functions have the same name `foo`.

You can write a wrapper function at the derived class, e.g.

```
struct Child : Base
{
    int foo(int x) { return Base::foo(x); }
    int foo(int, int, int);
};
```

Comment: @SebastianJohnHoward The other answers don't say it's possible to bring the specified overload into the derived class, they still bring all; then `delete` some. My approach is not to bring them, but add the necessary one. It might depend on the use scenario.

Comment: I understand. I withdraw my first comment.

Comment: @SebastianJohnHoward - As you can see it really is about managing inclusions and exclusions. If you want to **forward** just a few overloads, you'd best do as this answer suggests. However, if you want to **omit** just a few, then my answer is shorter. With your example, they are equivalent to an extent.

Comment: I like this answer. Somebody reading this in the production code doesn't go "rare syntax" and have to stop and think about what it means when the common syntax spells it out really easily.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to list both solutions presented in other answers, and detail how they differ.

```
struct Child : Base
{
  int foo(int x) { return Base::foo(x); }
  int foo(int, int, int) {  std::cout << 3; return 33; }
};
```

this does exactly what you want, but you have to repeat the signature.

A slightly different result is:

```
struct Child : Base
{
  using Base::foo;
  int foo(int,int)=delete;
  int foo(int, int, int) { std::cout << 3; return 314; }
};
```

To see how this is different, imagine we did this:

```
struct Grandkid : Child
{
  using Child::foo;
  int foo(double, double) { std::cout << 2; return 42; }
};
```

and we did:

```
Grandkid x;
x.foo(3,4);
```

In the case with `=delete`, this would generate a compiler error.

`3,4` prefers `int,int` over `double,double`.  When we `=delete` the `int,int` overload, it is still considered, selected, and we pick the `=delete`d one.  When we instead exclude it from overload resolution, `3,4` picks `double,double`.

Manual forwarding *excludes* `int,int` overload from being considered.  `=delete` does not.

This is most similar to the imaginary syntax of `using Base::foo(int);` (ie, only bringing in one of the parent overloads of `foo`).

Note that `Grandkid` is just one simple way to detect the difference.  The important thing is there is a difference between removing something from overload resolution, and `=delete`ing the overload.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9281eb9b22b7906) where it works, and [where it doesn't](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/384716c3028b1a4c).

Comment: Was there ever a proposal to allow selective forwarding with a using declaration? It looks *somewhat* useful.

Comment: @StoryTeller I am unaware of such; I think `using` was intended to handle the "mass case" of wanting to include the parent's overloads into overload resolution.  Forwarding methods, for when you wanted to cherry pick, already existed.

Comment: I suppose it wouldn't be any less verbose than an inline definition either, really.

Comment: BTW, fantastic comparative analysis. But I think that it's worth mentioning, `Grandkid` can still forward the overload from `Base` explicitly, if it so desires. So long as stuff are accessible of course.